# how to lowercase all the object properties(fieldnames) and remain as object and not array

Tags: php

yes, I have this object, and the properties represents the db table columns as the properties, but they are all in upper case...how to change all the properties of the object into lower case, without converting the object into array after shifting the properties from upper case to lower case ?..
i thought i can use 
`array_change_key_case`
but this one returns array when i need the object and not array
same with
 `get_class_vars` and `get_object_vars`

so how?

Comment: It would be easier to give you appropriate advice if we knew the technology you were using--for instance, what DB? What middle stack? Are you trying to rename this on the application tier or on a client, if so what language are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Your best option (and first choice) should be to intercept the object creation and make the properties lower case to begin with; that would be the cleanest and most performant.

If that is not possible for any reason and we are talking about a dumb object (of type `stdClass`) then the easiest is to go through an intermediate array and then into a new object:

```
$temp = (array)$old;
$new = (object)array_combine(array_map('strtolower', array_keys($temp)), $temp);
```

If the object is of another type then there is really no way to do what you suggest and you should step back and rethink the application from an earlier stage.

Comment: the object is of another type..when I tried your array funcs..it turned into and stdClass

Comment: @sasori: If the object is of another type then your problem cannot be solved "mechanically", so changing the case of the properties is not what you should be thinking about.